# Command Line Window in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Is it possible to have a command line window in the Sublime Text editor? For example, maybe a tab/buffer in the editor where I can enter commands to Cygwin, or a terminal over SSH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite new and has some limitations (eg no superuser control) but the Glue plugin provides editor intregration with various shells, cross platform.

[Glue at Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Glue)

[Documentation](http://gluedocs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Does it work with Cygwin? I'm linking Cygwin to the shellpath, and it's not working. :/

Comment: Do you mind submitting this as a new issue on the [Glue repository](https://github.com/chrissimpkins/glue/issues) with some details on the path that you are using?  I haven't done any testing with Cygwin but would be happy to look into the problems that you are having. -C